# An equation with a nested function

Tags: functional-equations

I'm trying to find the function $\eta(x)$ such that

$\eta(x) F(\eta(x))-G(\eta(x)) = \eta(x)H(x) - G(x)$

but I have no idea how to go about it, or where to look. Thanks for the inputs.

All functions can be assumed to be continuous, non-zero, non-decreasing on a real interval.

Comment: Do we know anything about F, G and H?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, edited to include.

Comment: What are $F,G$ and $H$?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  If you take $F$, $G$ and $H$ to be identically zero then $\eta$ can be any function you like.

Comment: They are non-zero monotone non-decreasing functions on an interval $[a,b]$. There is not much else I know about them.

Comment: Take $F(x)=G(x)=H(x)=x$ then solve $\eta^2(x)-(x+1)\eta(x)+x=0$

Comment: Where has this problem come from? If it's from a book, can you put a photo of the page itself? If not, where has it come from?

Comment: It is something I formulated, and does not come from a book. It is part of an elaborate setting where I am trying to solve for the social welfare maximizing function.